# Travel routes algorithm according to schedules

Tags: algorithm

There are many stations in a city, they are connected by train lines or/and bus lines. There are some schedules describing traveling between stations.

The classes can be:

Place(name, image, location, ...)

Schedule(from_place, to_place, distance, departure_time, arrival_time, ...)

I need to implement a function as below:

getRoutes(from_place, to_place, departure_time){ 
    ....
}

The function need to return top 5 fastest routes (a routes is an array of schedules).

One more thing: the traveller can transfer to other vehicles at same station and transfer time  will not be considered.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you ensure FIFO property in your netwok? The FIFO property guarantees that if a traveler leaves a station `i` for a station `j` at a given time,
any traveler leaving station `i` for station `j` at a later time will arrive later (or simultaneousely) at station `j`. If this is not the case and you have no other guarantees, then you might be in trouble.

Comment: There may be different lines between  two stations, such as a train line and a bus line. For a given type of line, FIFO is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be solvable via a modified Dijkstra, where edge costs from A to B are not static, but rather depend on the time when A was reached (you would be using times instead of distances), and edge weights reflect the time needed to arrive at B using the next available fastest-arriving schedule. At the end of a run, you would end with the fastest route from start to finish.

In order to find further routes, there are a few options. An easy one is to take the *k* segments (schedules) of the fastest route, and for each of these segments,

- remove it
- re-run the modified dijkstra to find the fastest route without that segment
- add it back

Note that you cannot know, until all *k* runs are finished, which segment-removal will result in a faster second-best arrival. After taking the shortest of the *k* runs as second-best route, you would look for the third-best route by repeating this process with the *t* segments in the second-best route (discarding the first-best route, if and when found, for the next contender).

Another way of computing *n*-best routes from start to finish is to further modify the time-aware Dijkstra to store not just the best arrival time (and parent schedule) to each node; but to store a list (sorted by arrival time) of such arrival-times and routes. In the finish node, this list would reflect all shortest paths, with the only draw-back that, instead of interrupting Dijkstra when the finish node is first reached, you would need to keep on running until it is reached for the *n*th time. Beware that, depending on your definition of "different route", there may not be 5 different routes from start to finish.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try your way, tucuxi.